# Output on label involving string

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FirstNumber = TextBox1.Text
    SecondNumber = TextBox2.Text
    Message = "The results are as follows:" & vbNewLine
    Message = Message & "Addition:" & FirstNumber + SecondNumber
    Label3.Text = Message

End Sub
```

I am using the code above in a program where I have declared Message As String. But why is it that on the second line the text "The results are as follows" doesn't appear even though I have included Message as part of the line?

Comment: because you create one string and that text is only in there once.  the second line of code simply concatenates (appends) some more text to it.  The second line only needs to be: `Message &= "Addition:" & FirstNumber + SecondNumber` as a shorthand way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your label isn't high enough to show two lines of text. Increase `Label3.Height` and it will be fixed.

```
Label3.Height = 30  ' 30 is an example of course
```